# Inserting data from a lookup column to single line of text column using rest API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

Subsystem is a lookup column and in other list I want to insert the value from this lookup column to Title column..

```
 data:  JSON.stringify({ '__metadata': { 'type':
 'SP.Data.SubsystemsListItem' }, 
              'TitleId': data.d.results[k].Subsystem.ID}),
```

this doesn't worked..

Answer (score 0):

Lookup Columns are a little bit tricky... You have to check if they are spelled correctly and if you e.g. access the items by REST you need to "expand" some values first:
http://www.threewill.com/using-the-expand-odata-query-option-in-sharepoint-2013/

But since you provided so little information (we need more code) it's almost impossible to guess where the problem is.

"doen't work" is an error message that is not very helpfull.

If you do AJAX calls (REST/CSOM/JCOM) it normaly helps to look if the requst actually gets to the server and to check what is the answer of the server. 
With the F12-Tools in common browsers and there the network analysis view you actually can solve 80% of these kind of problems.

Comment: the code works if I insert it to the same subsystem column in other list. But here the problem is that I need to insert it to Title column which is not lookup field.

Comment: Could you please post the code...?

And again:
What is the response (header)? 
What is the actual error message?

Comment: I simply stored the value from the lookup column to a variable and assigned it to title column..